# Закругление внутренний части border'a.

Tags: html, css

http://i28.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0111/1b/381aa651f1e4150371fad1a5ec1d321b.png

Нужно сделать так как на картинке. Слева то, что есть сейчас, справа то, что нужно.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле все проще:

```
border-radius: 20px; border:10px solid green
```

т.е. радиус надо задать гораздо больше чем толщина границы и тогда внутренние углы становятся тоже округлыми.

Comment: отличное свойство, жаль не все браузеры хавают!

Comment: Просто набиритесь терпения и подождите годик полтора =)

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.

Comment: Да пожалуйста. на счет всех не знаю, но последние версии Opera, Chrome, FF7 - работают одинаково с этим свойством. IE - ну это IE, там всегда все через одно место...

Comment: В IE10 поддержка css3, как и других html5 фич будет на достойном уровне, сам в шоке но это так...

Если они будут распостронять IE10 вместе с 8ой виндоа - глядишь дела пойдут получше.

****

Да и, насколько я знаю - MS чето там пытется выдумть для разработки desktop приложений исключительно средствами html5, но это так, слухи...

Как и то что уже ведутся работы над css4... 

Но я вам этого не писал :DD

Comment: Мечты-мечты, слава Богу распрощались с IE6, но если css3 нормальный будет только в 10 версии, то верстать под 7-й IE придется еще лет так 15 =)

Answer (score 2):

Можно двумя блоками, например:

внешнему блоку поставить border-radius и padding шириной рамки, background-color цвета рамки, внутреннему border-radius. У обоих рамку закруглить.

Comment: +1 и соответственно радиусы у внутреннего блока будет меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличный сайт: 
 [тык](http://border-radius.com/)

эксперементируйте

Comment: чето я кроме border-radius больше  ничего проставить не смог